# Adding XML tags dynamically based on count of particular tags in xml using XSLT

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I got a challenge to add xml tags dynamically based on count of one xml tag. For ex: I have 2 Creditor records in "CreditorPPContractParts" section in below xml as shown in test data.

```
 <PPPrivPropertyLine>
       <InsuredProperties>
          <Entry>
             <Buildings>
                <Entry>
                   <AlarmClass>None_De</AlarmClass>
                   <InterestType>OwnerOccupied_De</InterestType>
                   <BuildingStandard_De>Normal</BuildingStandard_De>
                </Entry>
             </Buildings>
             <ContractParts>
                <Entry>
                   <CreditorPPContractParts>
                      <Entry>
                         <ReferenceNumber>SSG-SGLAKTZN gel. wg. EU-DSGVO</ReferenceNumber>
                         <InsuranceCoverage>0</InsuranceCoverage>
                         <IssueDate>2016-09-08T00:00:00+02:00</IssueDate>
                         <Creditor>
                            <Contact>
                               <AddressBookUID>D73GLX</AddressBookUID>
                            </Contact>
                         </Creditor>
                      </Entry>
                      <Entry>
                         <ReferenceNumber>SSG-SGLAKTZN gel. wg. EU-DSGVO</ReferenceNumber>
                         <InsuranceCoverage>0</InsuranceCoverage>
                         <IssueDate>1979-10-17T00:00:00+01:00</IssueDate>
                         <Creditor>
                            <Contact>
                               <AddressBookUID>OAS5OE</AddressBookUID>
                            </Contact>
                         </Creditor>
                      </Entry>
                   </CreditorPPContractParts>
                </Entry>
             </ContractParts>
          </Entry>
       </InsuredProperties>
       <PolicyContactRoles></PolicyContactRoles>
    </PPPrivPropertyLine>
```

Now I have to create 2 entries in 'PolicyContactRoles' in same xml like below format since I've 2 creditor records above. We may have more than 2 creditor records but we need to add based on the creditor records count.

```html
  

    <PolicyContactRoles>
   <Entry>
      <AccountContactRole>
         <Subtype>Creditor_De</Subtype>
         <AccountContact>
            <Contact>
               <AddressBookUID>D73GLX</AddressBookUID>
            </Contact>
         </AccountContact>
      </AccountContactRole>
      <Subtype>PolicyCreditor_De</Subtype>
   </Entry>
   <Entry>
      <AccountContactRole>
         <Subtype>Creditor_De</Subtype>
         <AccountContact>
            <Contact>
               <AddressBookUID>OAS5OE</AddressBookUID>
            </Contact>
         </AccountContact>
      </AccountContactRole>
      <Subtype>PolicyCreditor_De</Subtype>
   </Entry>
</PolicyContactRoles>
```

I have done it for single record. I have no idea how to achieve for multiple creditor records. Please help me out, thank you!

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <!--copy all nodes and attributes-->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:param name="old2" select="PPPrivPropertyLine/InsuredProperties/Entry/ContractParts/Entry/CreditorPPContractParts/Entry/Creditor/Contact/AddressBookUID"/>
   <xsl:template match="PolicyContactRoles">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:if test="$old2 != ''">
            <Entry>
               <AccountContactRole>
                  <Subtype>Creditor_De</Subtype>
                  <AccountContact>
                     <Contact>
                        <AddressBookUID>
                           <xsl:value-of select="$old2"/>
                        </AddressBookUID>
                     </Contact>
                  </AccountContact>
               </AccountContactRole>
               <Subtype>PolicyCreditor_De</Subtype>
            </Entry>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And also, please use this XSLT Fiddle: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9dH/11

Comment: Where does the value of `<AddressBookUID>XN8DOW</AddressBookUID>` come from?

Comment: @michael.hor257k : Sorry Michael, i have updated wrongly. Corrected now. And thanks for the response. Issue resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just process the `Creditor` elements e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="PolicyContactRoles">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Creditor" mode="pcr"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Creditor" mode="pcr">
    <Entry>
               <AccountContactRole>
                  <Subtype>Creditor_De</Subtype>
                  <AccountContact>
                     <Contact>
                        <xsl:copy-of select=".//AddressBookUID"/>
                     </Contact>
                  </AccountContact>
               </AccountContactRole>
               <Subtype>PolicyCreditor_De</Subtype>
      </Entry>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Seriously!!! It's worked as expected. Perfect answer served in 5 mins. Great!! Thank you so much for your help. thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @Martin Honnen, i have come across the the same scenario but should not allow the duplicate record here while adding creditor records. Can you help me out on this too. thanks in Advance.
I have added if condition, but did not work:
<xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::AddressBookUID)">

Comment: @SwathiVenigalla, see any introduction to grouping/identitfying duplicates, like https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info, perhaps instead of `<xsl:apply-templates select="//Creditor" mode="pcr"/>` use `<xsl:for-each-group select="//Creditor" group-by=".//AddressBookUID"><xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="pcr"/></xsl:for-each-group>`. If that doesn't help, raise a new question with the necessary details.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have tried but XSLT 1.0 is not accepting the "for-each-group". Sure I will raise a new question with necessary details and will give you the link here. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Martin, created separate question with required details. Please refer below link. Thank you!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69010484/adding-xml-tags-dynamically-and-should-not-allow-duplicates-based-on-count-of-pa