# Adding XML tags dynamically and should not allow duplicates based on count of particular tags in xml using XSLT

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have challenge to add xml tags dynamically based on count of one xml tag and also should not allow duplicates (I am using XSLT 1.0). For ex: I have 3 Creditor records in "CreditorPPContractParts" section in below xml as shown in test data.

```html
<PPPrivPropertyLine>
       <InsuredProperties>
          <Entry>
             <Buildings>
                <Entry>
                   <AlarmClass>None_De</AlarmClass>
                   <InterestType>OwnerOccupied_De</InterestType>
                   <BuildingStandard_De>Normal</BuildingStandard_De>
                </Entry>
             </Buildings>
             <ContractParts>
                <Entry>
                   <CreditorPPContractParts>
                      <Entry>
                          <Creditor>
                            <Contact>
                               <AddressBookUID>D73GLX</AddressBookUID>
                            </Contact>
                         </Creditor>
                      </Entry>
                      <Entry>                         
                         <Creditor>
                            <Contact>
                               <AddressBookUID>OAS5OE</AddressBookUID>
                            </Contact>
                         </Creditor>
                      </Entry>
                          <Entry>                         
                         <Creditor>
                            <Contact>
                               <AddressBookUID>OAS5OE</AddressBookUID>
                            </Contact>
                         </Creditor>
                      </Entry>
                   </CreditorPPContractParts>
                </Entry>
             </ContractParts>
          </Entry>
       </InsuredProperties>
       <PolicyContactRoles></PolicyContactRoles>
    </PPPrivPropertyLine>
```

Now I have to create 3 entries in 'PolicyContactRoles' in same xml like below format since I've 3 creditor records above. We may have more than 3 creditor records but we need to add based on the creditor records count. As I said above we should not allow duplicates. We have one duplicate creditor record. so output should be 2 creditor entries.

```html
<PolicyContactRoles>
   <Entry>
      <AccountContactRole>
         <Subtype>Creditor_De</Subtype>
         <AccountContact>
            <Contact>
               <AddressBookUID>D73GLX</AddressBookUID>
            </Contact>
         </AccountContact>
      </AccountContactRole>
      <Subtype>PolicyCreditor_De</Subtype>
   </Entry>
   <Entry>
      <AccountContactRole>
         <Subtype>Creditor_De</Subtype>
         <AccountContact>
            <Contact>
               <AddressBookUID>OAS5OE</AddressBookUID>
            </Contact>
         </AccountContact>
      </AccountContactRole>
      <Subtype>PolicyCreditor_De</Subtype>
   </Entry>
</PolicyContactRoles>
```

I have done it using below XSLT script. but could not able to avoid the duplicates. Please help me out, thank you!

```html
<xsl:template match="PolicyContactRoles">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Creditor" mode="pcr"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Creditor" mode="pcr">
    <Entry>
               <AccountContactRole>
                  <Subtype>Creditor_De</Subtype>
                  <AccountContact>
                     <Contact>
                        <xsl:copy-of select=".//AddressBookUID"/>
                     </Contact>
                  </AccountContact>
               </AccountContactRole>
               <Subtype>PolicyCreditor_De</Subtype>
      </Entry>
</xsl:template>
```

And also, please use this XSLT Fiddle:https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9dH/13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to get only distinct creditors:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="creditor" match="Creditor" use="Contact/AddressBookUID" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PolicyContactRoles">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Creditor[count(. | key('creditor', Contact/AddressBookUID)[1]) = 1]">
            <Entry>
                <AccountContactRole>
                    <Subtype>Creditor_De</Subtype>
                    <AccountContact>
                        <Contact>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="Contact/AddressBookUID"/>
                        </Contact>
                    </AccountContact>
                </AccountContactRole>
                <Subtype>PolicyCreditor_De</Subtype>
            </Entry>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi michael.hor257k, Thanks for the quick solution. It worked but while I am integrating it in real time proj, getting different issue. Actually, along with Creditor entries we have 2 more existing entries with different subtypes [Policy_holder and BillingContact] in "PolicyContactRoles" section. Those 2 entries are missing if I apply your code. See this: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9dH/14

Comment: So do `<xsl:copy-of select="Entry"/>` before (or after) you add the new entries.